# A few questions about flashdrive ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

What is the main difference between having ubuntu downloaded on the computer and using a flashdrive to boot it on a computer? Can I still save things to the flashdrive like files or is it like a reboot of the whole thing everytime? Or is it just for that one computer that it is saved to and I would have to start from a clean slate with the other computers I use it on? Sorry for all the questions I am just really and new to the whole spectrum of of this kind of os.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is where you're booting from - the computer hard drive or USB drive. 
There is something called a persistence file you can create when you create the bootable USB drive if there is enough space left over. 
 Things you save to your persistence file should be available no matter which PC you boot it from.  That being said you could also save files to whichever HDD (hard drive disk) is present in the computer you are booting from.  Those would be local to the PC.  I wouldn't recommend writing too much onto a partition that another OS uses (like windows) 
 here is a link with a step by step to install as well: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop